# MySQL gather data JOIN

Tags: mysql

I currently have these two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `vocation` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `player_storage` (
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `key` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`,`key`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to execute the following query

```
SELECT
  a.value, 
  b.name,
  b.level, 
  b.vocation
FROM
  player_storage a,
  players b
  LEFT JOIN players_online c AS t
     ON c.player_id = b.id
WHERE
  a.player_id = b.id
  AND a.key = 6723
ORDER BY a.value DESC LIMIT 20
```

Thing is I also want to see if the record exists on the table players_online

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `players_online` (
  `player_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`player_id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

However my query seems to work but its not getting if the player_id exists on players_online

I only get the fields value, name, level, vocation but not a single field related to players_online

Comment: You don't have a field in your SELECT clause that is sourced from `players_online`, so I am not sure what the question is here.  You are also using an odd mix of old ANSI-89 join syntax with explicit join syntax. I would recommend using explicit syntax in all cases to help avoid problem with unexpected Cartessian joins.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN players_online c AS t` -- does this query execute? It looks like a syntax error, aliasing both `c` and `t`.

Comment: Except `as t` error it looks ok for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a field related to your "online" table.

For example:

```
SELECT ...,
IF(c.player_id IS NULL, 'offline', 'online') online
FROM ...
```

And sure, you must to fix issue with double alias in `players_online c As t`

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a17109/1)